# Why is my Ember Data store not updating correctly with Array Controller and Collection View?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to get an array of phone numbers to update back into the Data Store in ember/ember-data.  I've spent about a day and a half trying different data configurations but nothing seems to be working for me.

I have a JSFiddle reproduction here showing the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/Murcho/SwP4r/

To see the issue

- Click the "User Setting" link
- Change one of the name fields
- Change one of the Phone Number fields (phone numbers are in the array).
- Click onto the "Other Page" link
- Click back onto the "User Setting" link.

Any changes made to the name fields will have been persisted in the Data Store, but any changes made to the phone number fields will have been lost.

I've tried encapsulating the array data with two different `DS.Transform` objects:

```
// Custom Array Transforms
App.ArrayTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
    deserialize: function(serialized) {
        var arr = Ember.ArrayController.create();
        arr.set('content', serialized);
        return arr;
    },
    serialize: function(deserialized) {
        var arr = deserialized.get('content');
        return arr;
    }
});

App.RawTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
    deserialize: function(serialized) {
        return serialized;
    },
    serialize: function(deserialized) {
        return deserialized;
    }
});
// END Custom Array transforms
```

The UserSetting template is:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="userSetting">
     <ul>
        <li>First Name : {{input type="text" value=model.firstName}}</li>
        <li>Last Name : {{input type="text" value=model.lastName}}</li>
        {{view App.PhoneCollectionView content=model.userSetting.emergencyPhones}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

The `App.PhoneCollectionView` used in that template is:

```
App.PhoneCollectionView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    itemViewClass: 'App.ArrayEntryView'
});
```

And finally the `App.ArrayEntryView` used in the `App.PhoneCollectionView`:

```
//HBS
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="array-entry">
    <li><label>Phone Number {{view.adjustedIndex}}</label>{{input type="text" value=view.content}}</li>
</script>


//JS
App.ArrayEntryView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "array-entry",
    adjustedIndex: function() {
        return this.get('contentIndex') + 1;
    }.property()
});
```

It might just be a case that I've got too many views in between the data store and the final view, which is causing the loss of binding, however everywhere I've read has pointed me in this direction so there must be something I'm doing wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone comes across the issue, I have managed to fix this.

The problem was the array of information I was indexing was an array of strings, which ember seems to not be able to track on it's own :

```
App.UserSetting.FIXTURES = [
    { id: 1, emergencyPhones: ["12345678", "5555555", "123123123"] }
];
```

By wrapping each of the strings in an object, Ember was able to correctly propagate the information back to the data store :

```
App.UserSetting.FIXTURES = [
    { id: 1, emergencyPhones: [{string: "12345678"}, {string: "5555555"}, {string: "123123123"}] }
];
```